# ARGOCD - Failed to create Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-eks, argocd

We've installed ARGOCD using Helm charts on our EKS Cluster with GitHub OAUTH SSO for authentication and default Admin role for all users. However, we're facing an issue where the Helm repository paths aren't recognized while creating applications in ARGOCD,

While creating the application inside the argocd, Helm Repo must be detected and Application path must be displayed while creating ARGOCD Application,so that helm chart values files can be selected, As The paths are empty and not being recognised and displaying as empty so unable to create the application

[ARGOCD Paths Issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88a58.png)

- Added the config maps used for ARGOCD for ref

```
# Config Map
apiVersion: v1
data:
  controller.log.format: text
  controller.log.level: info
  controller.operation.processors: "10"
  controller.repo.server.timeout.seconds: "60"
  controller.self.heal.timeout.seconds: "5"
  controller.status.processors: "20"
  otlp.address: ""
  redis.server: argocd-redis:6379
  repo.server: argocd-repo-server:8081
  reposerver.log.format: text
  reposerver.log.level: info
  reposerver.parallelism.limit: "0"
  server.basehref: /argo
  server.dex.server: http://argocd-dex-server:5556
  server.disable.auth: "false"
  server.enable.gzip: "false"
  server.insecure: "false"
  server.log.format: text
  server.log.level: info
  server.rootpath: /argo
  server.staticassets: /shared/app
  server.x.frame.options: sameorigin
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: argocd
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: argocd
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-30T15:47:21Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cmd-params-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-5.6.0
  name: argocd-cmd-params-cm
  namespace: argocd
  resourceVersion: "361045"
  uid: 0f2fc681-887a-eeee-a688e-7015df6d3525
```

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  admin.enabled: "false"
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  dex.config: "      connectors:\n        - type: github\n          id: github\n          name:
    GitHub\n          config:\n            clientID: clientidxx\n            clientSecret:
    clientsecretxx\n            orgs:\n              - name:
    githuborgxx\n                teams:\n                                - teamxx\n
    \               "
  exec.enabled: "false"
  server.rbac.log.enforce.enable: "false"
  timeout.hard.reconciliation: "0"
  timeout.reconciliation: 180s
  url: https://xx.xx.com/argo
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: argocd
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: argocd
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-30T15:47:21Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-5.6.0
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
  resourceVersion: "361044"
  uid: 0080dce0-67f4-ssws2-8aa7-c72ed5a169bb
```

Helm Repo must be detected and Application path must be displayed while creating ARGOCD Application

NOTE: ARGOCD can able to read the repo as branches are being visible while adding the Repo only the paths are displayed as blank, So Unable to add the values.yml